# Android Studio hotkey for "do refactor"

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio I can start renaming via `Shift + F6`. Then Android Studio shows me a box telling me about the changes and presents me with a "Do Refactor"-button. When hovering over the button Android Studio shows me no information about a hotkey I could press. Is there a hotkey for that button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that it works with pressing `Alt + d`.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a keyboard shortcut for every button.

Usually program developers provide hotkeys just for most used basic functions.

There is `Shift+F6` in Android Studio for refactoring and that's the closest option to get the functionality you want.